# NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage comes up empty in 10.11?

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-elcapitan

Can anyone else verify this issue in 10.11?

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];  
NSLog(@"cookieStorage count is %lu", [[cookieStorage cookies] count]);
```

When I run this in El Capitan, cookieStorage comes up (null) where I get the complete set of cookies in 10.10 and earlier. Is anyone else doing anything with cookies in 10.11 - this seems like a pretty significant bug?

EDIT with answer:

Not (yet) documented in the NSHTTPCookieStorage class reference is the new method for 10.11:

```
//access to Safari cookie storage
[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedCookieStorageForGroupContainerIdentifier:@"Cookies"]
```

Each application has its own cookie storage in 10.11. With thanks to the answer to this question: [stringWithContentsOfURL cookie jar in El Capitan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32921572/stringwithcontentsofurl-cookie-jar-in-el-capitan)

Some more info in the WWDC 15 session on Networking with NSURLSession.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out 10.11 to sandbox every individual app like iOS.
Here is my solution.

```
 // To read cookies from Safari
NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage  = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedCookieStorageForGroupContainerIdentifier:@"Cookies"];

 // To write cookies to the app
for (NSHTTPCookie *aCookies in [storage cookies]){
    [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookie:aCookies];
}
```

Hope this would be helpful.